# Does anyone pray according to Rambam's Seder Tefila?

Tags: tefilla, rambam, prayer-book, nuschaot

I wonder if among the new wave of *Talmidei haRambam*, there might be anyone using a *siddur* that uses Rambam's language of prayer exclusively, as recorded in the *Mishneh Torah* ([here](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/27.htm)).

Comment: Are you looking to find a Rabbi who does/recommends this, or just the knowledge that someone, somewhere, decided to do this?

Comment: It is my understanding that the Rambam's Seder HaTefila is similar to the Yemenite Nusach.

Comment: I pray this way.

Comment: It seems you have an answer, Izmargadi: Mori (see just above) prays this way. Is that what you were seeking? I mean, does that answer your question? cc @DoubleAA

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob Which _Siddur_ do you use?

Comment: @tamir Sefar ahabo nosa7 hatafillo. But has to be from Mori gafe7. I also use his sia7 yarusholayeem sometimes. Also got a free app on the iPhone called ticlal(spell it in hebrew when searching for it in the store)

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob (1) I would think using the _Seder Tefilah_ that's in the _Mishneh Torah_ for prayer would be more than a little inconvenient, unless you have it memorized. Do you have it memorized? (2) I read somewhere that the Baladi _Nusach_ in _Si'ach Yerushalayim_ differs in some places from the ancient _Tiklal_ s, and elsewhere that the _Tiklal_ s differ in some places from the _Mishneh Torah_ ( even from the Qafih edition). Are you sure you use, in your prayer, "Rambam's language of prayer **exclusively**"( even saying that Qafih's version in the _Mishneh Torah_ is the correct one)?

Comment: @tamir yes I remember it. And indeed sia7 yarusholayeem has changed a few things and added a few things here and there which I don't say. But I trust Mori gafe7's mt for proper nosa7. I forgot where but he himself explains why his "own" siddur was changed.

Comment: http://net-sah.org/product/25261

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov, if I may, how does the Tiklal differ from Siddur HaRambam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such a siddur, first published in 2006 and arranged by Gil Kobrin/Amminadav, who operates a printing press called Derushah Publications.

It's called *Siddur Mesorath Moshe*, and was, [as the arranger noted](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/Yemenite_group/conversations/messages/970), "drawn from the liturgical arrangement found in the legal code of our teacher and master Moses b. Maimon (Maimonides), in the appendix entitled "Arrangement of the Prayer" of the second book of the Mishneh Torah, Sefer Ahavah."

[Here](http://markov.podval.org/Rambam_Siddur.pdf) is a pdf of that siddur. I haven't been able to find any haskamot or even public awareness of this siddur, besides the Yemenite Jewish forum linked above, but this at least shows there is contemporary evidence of *talmidei HaRambam* following the Rambam's language of prayer.

Comment: I would also like to point out that this siddur is 1000% better than sia7 yarusholayeem or and other ticlal out at the moment.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob & Aryeh Does any of you happen to have the PDF? The link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @NBZ It seems to be for sale http://www.lulu.com/shop/gil-amminadav/siddur-mesorath-moshe/hardcover/product-15123475.html

Comment: pdf link not working

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84460/759